# Impact of Subscriber status NULL

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, subscriber

I have some email addresses with status "null" in the All Subscriber list. Can emails be delivered on this status? I ask because I have a gap and I wonder why I have so few sendings and I have noticed this status "zero" with many subscribers.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what do you mean by status = "null" ... as the are are only 4 possible status for a subscriber in SFMC i.e., ACTIVE, RETURNED UNDELIVERABLE, UNSUBSCRIBED [https://i.ibb.co/G9Ts7Y5/SS.png]... Please provide more details of your issue.

Comment: When I search for the email address directly in the All-Subscriber List, it is shown as active. When I query it using the Query Studio, it is displayed as status = zero.

Comment: Hi @Maik, I haven't yet experienced such issue. Can you please update your question with your SQL query and screenshot of the data extension?